# Running a btrfs RAID 5 array on Arch Linux

Tags: raspberry-pi, raid, btrfs, kernel-panic

For two weeks, I've been trying to run my Raspberry Pi (model B) as root from a btrfs RAID 5 without success.

The RAID runs on three 1TB disks `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`. The three disks were wiped with `wipefs -a /dev/sdX` then I copied the root partition on the SD card of the Pi to one disk; `dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p5 of=/dev/sdb`. I repair-checked the disk with `fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sdb` and resized it to fit the 1TB with `resize2fs /dev/sdb`.

Then I converted the ext4 filesystem on the disk to btrfs with label `RAID` using `btrfs-convert -l RAID /dev/sdb`. Lastly, I mounted the disk using `mount /dev/sdb /mnt` and added the other two disks with `btrfs device add /dev/sdb` and `btrfs device add /dev/sdc` and converted it to RAID 5 using `btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid5 -mconvert=raid5 /mnt`. `btrfs filesystem show` shows me the three disks, all working.

Until here everything works fine; I can see all files and folders in `/mnt`.

I installed `mkinitcpio` and added `btrfs` and `raid456` to `MODULES`. I didn't include `btrfs` in hooks due to the bug in mkinitcpio (See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Btrfs#BTRFS:_open_ctree_failed). Then I ran `mkinitcpio -g /boot/initrd` to create an initrd file in `/boot`.

In the `config.txt` file, I have tried the following to load `initrd`:

```
initramfs initrd 0x00a00000
initramfs initrd 0x00800000
initramfs initrd 0x00f00000
```

In `cmdline.txt` I have tried:

```
root=/dev/sda rw rootwait rootfstype=btrfs initrd=0x00a00000
root=/dev/sda rw rootwait rootfstype=btrfs initrd=0x00800000
root=/dev/sda rw rootwait rootfstype=btrfs initrd=0x00f00000
```

During boot I get:

```
BTRFS: device label RAID devid 1 transid 2640 /dev/root
BTRFS: info (device sda): disk space caching is enabled
BTRFS: failed to read the system array on sda
BTRFS: open_ctree failed
```

then the kernel panics.

My questions are:

- How can I point to my btrfs RAID 5 with the "root=" command in cmdline.txt
- How can I ensure that the `initrd` is loaded (I tried several addresses and am not even sure if it is loaded).
- ...or simply: how do I get this working?

Comment: It looks to me like it is loading the initramfs and using the correct root; that error is from the `BTRFS` module, so it must be loaded, and it refers to `sda`.   I did a quick google for `BTRFS: open_ctree failed` and [found this](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Btrfs-zero-log), which seems pertinent.